# codeigniter form validation with define CONSTANT

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

i define a constant in /application/config/abc.php

```
define('MINI_LENGTH', 5);
```

then in the /application/controllers/abc.php

```
$config_form = array(array(
    'field' => 'name',
    'label' => 'First name',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[MINI_LENGTH]'),
```

it is not working and i got an error message :
"The xxx field must be at least MINI_LENGTH characters in length."

which part did i missed out or done wrongly? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$config_form = array(array(
     'field' => 'name',
     'label' => 'First name',
     'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length['.MINI_LENGTH.']'),
```

I haven't tested it though

Answer (score 0):

it very easy:

```
$config_form = array(array(
    'field' => 'name',
    'label' => 'First name',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length['.MINI_LENGTH.']'),
```